# Releasing a pokemon

Tags: pokemon-series

[This article on Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Released_Pok%C3%A9mon) says that:

> Released Pokémon cannot be found again in the wild

Does it mean that

- Only the very same pokemon you just released, with all its stats, learned moves and the nickname it had when you released it won't be found anywhere in the game (wild) so that you won't ever be able to encounter it again and re-capture

**OR**

- The whole pokemon type will be "blacklisted" from *suddenly appearing* in the wild to attack you?

I haven't ever released a pokemon when I played, so I don't quite understand what that rule means.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The former.

Once you release a Pokémon, that individual Pokémon is essentially deleted from the game. This does not affect your ability to find more of the same species of Pokémon in the wild.

Comment: You should clarify the option. Most people understand "the former", but some aren't that good at English. Something like (**a**) would really help, i think.

Answer (score -5):

I have released countless(seven) pokemon. Mostly due to the fact that I had more of that pokemon. You can release them and not worry about not seeing the entire species again. Just that one singular Pokemon won't be seen again. Basically option a.

Comment: This answer doesn't really seem to add anything that wasn't already stated in the existing answer.

Comment: still an answer right.

Comment: Duplicate answers are discouraged (as you may have noticed from its current rating) and may be subject to deletion.